# Process delayed PayPal payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Can you somehow ask the user to approve a payment and process this very payment at a later time? Concretely, I have a marketplace, where a user A can request some product from other user B. I want to charge the moment user A receives his product but I want user B to be sure to not create his product for nothing, so I want the approve for the payment right at the moment user A inquires his request.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of Delayed Chain Payment. So whenever you want to pay the secondary receiver you will need to call the `ExecutePayment`. This payment to secondary receiver could be delayed upto 90 days.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/